# Looking for java classes by tags or labels

Tags: java, tags, label, documentation

I'm trying again to find a particular java class by name in our huge project and I don't know where it is and what is its name. I only know what is its functionality and I think its functionality could be described by some tags or labels like "writer", "database", "configuration" and "model". And its final name is "DbMmdImporter".

And I was wondering if there was a good way to use tags or labels in program documentation to simplify searching in code. Kind of similar to https://zapier.com/blog/how-to-use-tags-and-labels/ for files.
Does anyone think

1. it could be useful?
2. such usage of tags or labels in exist in program documentation?

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA.